# Async task didn't run - c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **btnSave Event:** *in this event i wana update datagridview but it's not working :(*

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
            {
                Remember remember = new Remember();

                remember.RememberTitle = txtTitle.Text;
                remember.RememberDate = dateTimePickerRememberDate.Value.Date;
                remember.RememberTime = dateTimePickerRememberTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
                remember.RememberContent = txtDescription.Text;
                remember.RememberTransaction = false;
                remember.RememberExpire = false;

                var res  = await Rep_App.NewRemember(remember).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (res)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
    //this line did not executed
                    await GetRemembers();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("...");
                }
            }
        }
```

> **GetRemember method :**

```
private async Task GetRemembers()
    {
        try
        {
            // Instantiate a new DBContext
            ParkingManager.Context.DataBaseContext dbContext = new ParkingManager.Context.DataBaseContext(PublicVariables.ConnectionString);
            // Call the LoadAsync method to asynchronously get the data for the given DbSet from the database.
            await dbContext.Remembers.LoadAsync().ContinueWith(loadTask =>
            {
                // Bind data to control when loading complete
                remembersBindingSource.DataSource = dbContext.Remembers.ToList();

            }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MessagesStruct.Exception);
        }
    }
```

**GetRemember() did not execute in Save Event but when the form loaded GetRemember() executed completely, what's wrong?**

Comment: Remove all those `.ConfigureAwait(false);` and `ContinueWith`. `.ConfigureAwait(false);` means execution *won't* return to the UI thread. Don't try to fix what isn't broken. The *real* error is creating a DbContext without `using` - that leaks DbContext instances and any objects they've loaded

Comment: You wouldn't need `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` to try to return to the UI thread if you hadn't used `ConfigureAwait(false)`. That doesn't work anyway, because at this point the current sync context is the background thread, not the UI thread

Comment: Another problem is using `dbContext.Remembers.LoadAsync()` instead of just loading what you want with `remembersBindingSource.DataSource = await dbContext.Remembers.ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *caused* by `ConfigureAwait(false)` and `ContinueWith`. `ConfigureAwait(false)` will cause execution to continue on a background thread instead of getting back to the UI. `LoadAsync` isn't needed either, the data will be loaded by `ToList` or `ToListAsync()`.

EF Core and async/await don't need so much code. All of this can be replaced with

```
var res  = await Rep_App.NewRemember(remember);
if (res)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
    using(var dbContext = new DataBaseContext(PublicVariables.ConnectionString))
    {
        remembersBindingSource.DataSource = await dbContext.Remembers.ToListAsync();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("...");
}
```